# req.body.mandrill_events and req.mandrill_events both undefined

Tags: node.js, express, mandrill

I am trying to receive e-mail through Mandrill like this:

```
app.post('/mail/enquiry', function (req, res) {
    console.log('request at mail/enquiry');
    console.log(req.mandrill_events);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

**I am trying to find the message content from the POST request body.** It is more difficult than I expected :(

Neither req.mandrill_events nor req.body.mandrill_events work.

req.body is something that begins with:

```
{ domain: null,
_events { finish [Function]},
```

Comment: Can you show the body parsing middleware you're `use()`ing before this route?

Comment: app.use(bodyParser()); was after the inbound email route. That was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express 4 evaluates all middleware and routes in the order in which they were added, so you need to make sure body parsing middleware comes before your route in some way.

Comment: I figured since everything is "async" their order doesn't matter.